# $t \geq 1$ and triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

Let a, b and c be three distinct points in a vector space V with an inner product. If $d(a,c) = d(a,b) + d(b,c)$ then $c-a = t(b-a)$ with $t \geq 1$.

I'm trying to show (without success so far) that the equality in the triangle inequality holds for the vectors (c-a) e (b-a), because, the equality holds if and only if (c-a) or (b-a) is a nonnegative multiple of the other.

Any tips?

Thank you very much.

Comment: First prove for $a=0.$

Comment: Is the metric $d$ induced by a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $V$ ?

Comment: @Medo. That's how I'm trying to solve it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. This case has already been done.

Comment: You've already proven for $a=0?$ Then $d(x,a)=d(x-a,0),$ so you are essentially finished.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. I will check your tip. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. I can't see how to use your hint to prove that $t \geq 1$, because $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Anyway, I'll keep trying. Thanks.